# $KL$ is normal over $F$ if both $K$ and $L$ are normal over $F$

Tags: field-theory

Let $K$ and $L$ be extensions of $F$. Show that $KL$ is normal over $F$ if both $K$ and $L$ are normal over $F$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sigma : KL \rightarrow \overline{F}$ be an embedding in an algebraic closure containing $K$ and $L$. Since $K/F$ and $L/F$ are normal, $\sigma(K) = K$ and $\sigma(L) = L$.

Then $\sigma(KL) = \sigma(K)\sigma(L) = KL$, so $KL/F$ is also normal.

Comment: How about algebraic extension? Do we have the same result?